# Conversion from angle to vector3 does not work correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a game about knife that goes up when you left click, rotates in mid-air and moves in the direction it's facing when you right click. Though, for some reason, it does not work at all!
[knife](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zEZk.png)
[video](https://streamable.com/ohd1jg)

```
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
    private float _rotationSpeed;
    private void Start()
    {
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    public void Jump()
    {
        _rigidbody.AddForce(Vector3.up * 600, ForceMode.Force);
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Jump();
            _rotationSpeed = 250;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse1))
        {
            _rotationSpeed = 0;

            float angle = transform.rotation.x * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            Vector3 direction = new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(angle), Mathf.Sin(angle));
            Debug.Log(direction);

            _rigidbody.AddForce(direction * 600, ForceMode.Force);
        }
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0,_rotationSpeed, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: Well it looks like you dont just apply direction of forward. Which surely is all you need when it's already facing the direction you need

Comment: what exactly do you mean? i'm new to unity and do not understand....

Comment: Exactly that. You are calculating an angle when you are already at the angle. Hence it is not doing what you thought. Its nothing to do with unity. Its logic.